# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Properties ....Properties.php

Tags: php

I have the Class Database with the error    Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Properties ....Properties.php(Properties is Near implementation of the java.util.Properties API for PHP 5 Copyright (C) 2005 Craig Manley )

```
  <?php
     include_once("common/libs/Properties.php");
        // if (!class_exists('Properties')) {
        //  require_once("common/libs/Properties.php");
        // }
        class Database {
          var dbhost;



            function __construct() {

                $dbIpAddressProp = new Properties();
        //          $dbIpAddressProp->load(file_get_contents('./confEMS',FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH));
        //          $this->dbhost = $dbIpAddressProp->getProperty("dbIpAddress");   

            }
            function __destruct() {
                pg_close($this->dbconn);
        //      echo 'destruct';
            }

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: and what's inside Properties.php ?

Comment: The error message should give you a bit more information, such as where properties was originally declared and where you're trying to redeclare it

Comment: It is an API: Near implementation of the java.util.Properties API for PHP 5        Copyright (C) 2005 Craig Manley

Answer (score 0):

You might be including `Properties.php` in your other php files more than once.
First make sure that you're not declaring class `Properties` twice in `Properties.php`. Then, you need to check all of your includes. I strongly recommend you to check error stack using *xdebug* or anything. Then you can find out what is this error coming from.

You should use `include_once` whenever you want to include `properties.php`. (Because it contains a class, and a class cannot be redeclared)